# Nest arguments and env vars in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
setlocal
set BuildRoot=d:\
set OutDir=%Tmp%
call :GenerateBaseLine "Build"
goto :eof

:GenerateBaseLine
call dir /s /b /A-D %%1Root% > %OutDir%\%1Baseline.txt
echo "wrote dir /s /b /A-D" %%1Root% %OutDir%\%1Baseline.txt

goto :eof
```

The output I get is:

```
>setlocal
>set BuildRoot=d:\
>set OutDir=C:\Users\erickul\AppData\Local\Temp
>call :GenerateBaseLine "Build"
>call dir /s /b /A-D %1RootOutDir1Baseline.txt
File Not Found
>echo "wrote dir /s /b /A-D" %1RootOutDir1Baseline.txt
"wrote dir /s /b /A-D" %1RootOutDir1Baseline.txt
>goto :eof
>goto :eof
```

What is wrong with this code?  I am expecting

```
%%1Root%
```

To evaluate to D:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion` to make your variable expand as you expect. Try the following:

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set BuildRoot=d:\
set OutDir=%Tmp%
call :GenerateBaseLine "Build"
goto :eof

:GenerateBaseLine
call dir /s /b /A-D !%1Root! > %OutDir%\%1Baseline.txt
echo "wrote dir /s /b /A-D" !%1Root! %OutDir%\%1Baseline.txt

goto :eof
```

The problem is of course with the line `call dir /s /b /A-D %%1Root% > %OutDir%\%1Baseline.txt` - and more specifically, starts at `%%1Root%`. You are obviously trying to expand `%1`, then expand `%BuildRoot%`, however CMD will first replace `%%` with `%`, then try to expand `% > %` (expands to null), then `%\%` (also null). Leaving you with `%1RootOutDir1Baseline.txt`.

With delayed Expansion enabled, CMD will first expand `%1`, `%OutDir%`, and `%1` - then expand `!BuildRoot!`.